# What is the difference between subprocess.run & subprocess.check_output?

Tags: python, subprocess

I am trying to send two simple commands using `subprocess.run`  & trying to store results in a variable then print it but for one arg the output is coming for `subprocess.run`  & for other its empty

Arg are "**help"** & **"adb devices"**

command I am sending which returns the output

```
result = subprocess.run("help", capture_output=True, text=True, universal_newlines=True)
print(result.stdout)
```

but this command  with a different arg is not returning

```
result = subprocess.run("adb devices", capture_output=True, text=True, universal_newlines=True)
print(result.stdout)
```

If I try the same command with `subprocess.checkoutput` it returns the output can anyone explain what exactly is going on here
Is there any specific  usage scenario's  for these command's like when to use which one ?

```
c = subprocess.check_output(
        "adb devices", shell=True, stderr=subprocess.STDOUT)

print(c)
output - b'List of devices attached\r\n\r\n'
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It is because from the python documentation here:
[run method](https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.run)

*run* method accepts the first parameter as arguments and not string.

So you can try passing the arguments in a list as:

```
result = subprocess.run(['abd', 'devices'], capture_output=True, text=True, universal_newlines=True)
```

Also,
[check_output](https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.check_output) method accepts args but it has a parameter call **"shell = True"** Therefore, it works for multi-word args.

If you want to use the run method without a list, add shell=True in the run method parameter. (I tried for "man ls" command and it worked).

Comment: `universal_newlines` is apparently equivalent to the newer `text` argument, so it could be removed, as far as I understand? https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.run